# consolidating terms with conditional probability

Tags: probability

problem:

> A coin is biased so that P(H) = .6. Toss it 10 times. Find the probability of at least 9 heads given that you got at least 8 heads.

answer key (in part):

> *P(at least 9H | at least 8H)* = $\frac{P(at\ least\ 9H\ and\ at\ least\ 8H)}{P(at\ least\ 8H)}$ = $\frac{P(at\ least\ 9H)}{P(at\ least\ 8H)}$

I don't understand how the numerator simplifies here. If anything, I would have expected *P(at least 8H)* since *P(8H or 9H or 10H)* includes *P(9H or 10H)*.

Comment: The first "and" in the answer should be "given".

Comment: Sorry, I miscopied. Changed "P(at least 9H and at least 8H)" to "P(at least 9H | at least 8H)"

Comment: Let $X$ be the random variable corresponding to the number of heads. "At least 9 heads" means $X \geq 9$. Similarly, "at least 8 heads" means $X \geq 8$. The intersection of the events "$X \geq 8$" and "$X \geq 9$" is $X \geq 9$. Draw it on a number line, perhaps, if the intuition is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> P(8H or 9H or 10H) includes P(9H or 10H)

or more precisely

> (8H or 9H or 10H) includes (9H or 10H)

Yes, and therefore saying that both occur simultaneously is the same as saying the second occurs.